# Cron Jobs in CakePHP have suddenly stopped

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, ssh, cron

I'm working on a system that is built with CakePHP 3.5, this system has multiple Cron Jobs that run throughout the day.

These cron jobs have always been executed in the following format:

```
/home/myuser/public_html/bin/cake shell_name command_name
```

When the crons run they usually output their progress in the default system email that the server sends, for example:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v3.4.11 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /home/myuser/public_html/src/
PHP : 5.6.31
---------------------------------------------------------------
Starting Thirty Minute Report Email Cron (JSON and PDF files).... 
 - Report 1 complete
 - Report 2 complete
Report emails sent.
Cron Finished.
```

Yesterday, with no changes to the code, these crons have stopped working.

**Now all that is output is the CakePHP 3.5 Shell Helper:**

```
Welcome to CakePHP v3.4.11 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : src
Path: /home/myuser/public_html/src/
PHP : 5.6.31
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:

* app:  src
* root: /home/myuser/public_html
* core: /home/myuser/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp

Available Shells:

[Bake] bake

[Migrations] migrations

[CORE] cache, i18n, orm_cache, plugin, routes, server

[app] console, backups, tasks

To run an app or core command, type `cake shell_name [args]`
To run a plugin command, type `cake Plugin.shell_name [args]`
To get help on a specific command, type `cake shell_name --help`
```

**What is strange, is that if I run these commands via SSH (on the live production server) then they execute no problem, they also execute on localhost too.**

I'm following the correct format as described in CakePHP docs, here's my shell:

```
namespace App\Shell;

use Cake\Console\Shell;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

class TasksShell extends Shell {

    /*****
    *** SENDS THE REPORT EMAIL AT A THIRTY MINUTE INTERVAL
    *****/
    public function thirtyMinReport() {
      /** CODE **/
    }

}
```

and the cron being run is:

```
/home/myuser/public_html/bin/cake tasks thirty_min_report
```

Today I've also tried variations of it:

```
/home/myuser/public_html/bin/cake tasks thirtyMinReport
/home/myuser/public_html/bin/cake Tasks thirtyMinReport
php /home/myuser/public_html/bin/cake.php Tasks thirtyMinReport
cd /home/myuser/public_html && bin/cake Tasks thirtyMinReport
```

I have also found somebody else having the same issue on the CakePHP site [here](http://discourse.cakephp.org/t/cakephp-cron-job-problem-in-cpanel/2160), however that is still unresolved too.

**What can I be overlooking that is stopping the cron shell_name and command_name from being found?**

Comment: what use does cron run under? can you su to that user and test it that way.

Comment: @rtfm They are all run as root, and i've logged into SSH to test with root, still the same.

Comment: have you tested non cake cronjobs?

Comment: Good idea! I just tested a non-cake cron now... executed no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who was having trouble, I managed to find the answer to this myself.

For some reason unknown to me, the server php config had been updated, and now `register_argc_argv` was set to Off.

I re-enabled this and the cron jobs are working again.

```
register_argc_argv = On
```

This edit was made to `/opt/alt/php56/etc/php.ini`